# Programmatically altering NSIndexPath in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm implementing AdMob in a `UITableView` by putting banner ad in the first row of a section. I'm most of the way there implementing it, however I'm having a tough time getting `cellForRowAtIndexPath` to work as desired.

This is what my `numberOfRowsInSection` looks like:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    var count = Int()
    if let sections = fetchedResultsController.sections {
        let currentSection = sections[section]
        count = currentSection.numberOfObjects
        count = count + 1 // add another row for an ad
    }
    return count
}
```

My `cellForRowAtIndexPath` looks like this:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, var cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        let adCell: BannerAdTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(BannerAdTableViewCell.reuseIdentifier(), forIndexPath: indexPath) as! BannerAdTableViewCell
        // customization
        return adCell
    } else {
        // Cell for vanilla item to display
        // TODO: fix indexpath here. need to add 1
        let newIndexPath = indexPath.indexPathByAddingIndex(indexPath.row+1)
        indexPath = newIndexPath

        // Cell for a Routine
        let customCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(RoutineSelectionTableViewCell.reuseIdentifier(), forIndexPath: indexPath) as! RoutineSelectionTableViewCell
        let routine = fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! SavedRoutines

        customCell.routineNameLabel.text = routine.routineTitle

        return customCell
    }
}
```

I know I need to adjust the value of the `indexPath` to account for an extra row in the `indexPathSection`, but everything I've tried triggers out of bounds exceptions of some sort. Any feedback would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What happens if you remove the following lines `let newIndexPath = indexPath.indexPathByAddingIndex(indexPath.row+1)
        indexPath = newIndexPath` and use actual indexPath ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`indexPathByAddingIndex`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSIndexPath_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSIndexPath/indexPathByAddingIndex:) adds a new index, it does not increment a value of an index but adds one. If you previously had two indices / dimensions (section and row) you now have 3 indices / dimension: section, row and "the newly added one".

> Provides an index path containing the indexes in the receiving index path and another index.

What you should do instead is either create a new `NSIndexPath` by hand. And I do not think you need to add one, but subtract one, since the item at index 1 should actually be the element in your result at index 0:

```
let customIndexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: indexPath.row - 1, inSection: indexPath.section)
```

which you then use to access the "correct" `routine` at the right index:

```
let routine = fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(customIndexPath) as! SavedRoutines
```

Your call to `tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` should stay the same and still pass in the *default* `indexPath`.

Comment: Thank you! That makes perfect sense. I'm returning the right objects in `lldb`, but for some reason it's saying there's a `nil` value for `customCell.routineNameLabel.text`. `lldb`'s saying there's a value for `routine` + `routine.routineTitle` and I'm able to `po` their attributes. I'm also able to `po` a value for `customCell`, but it's saying there's a nil value for `customCell.routineNameLabel.text`. I'm going to recheck the wiring. I think adding an extra prototype might have broken something.

Comment: No idea why, but Xcode didn't like my `RoutineSelectionTableViewCell` after I implemented the changes you suggested. I went to Interface Builder, nuked the old connections, rewired them, cleaned cache and rebuilt and it worked. Thank you again.

Comment: @AdrianB that sounds strange, but glad to have been of help!